# Win7 Unable to create new Folder on Network Drive

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-explorer

Using Explorer I'm able to create a new folder on the harddrive with not problem, but when I try to create a new folder on my network drive, Explorer hangs and just keeps creating new folders.
I have to shutdown Explorer to get it to stop, and then I have to delete all the new folders that were created....  "New Folder", "New Folder (1)", "New Folder (2)", "New Folder (3)", etc. Sometimes as many as 100+.

The Network is a SnapServer NAS device.

Comment: That sounds quite impossible. What do the names of the folders look like? Also some more info would help about your network structure and where the network shares are located.

Comment: The Network is a SnapServer NAS device.  When I click on the "New Folder" button, it appears that Explorer has frozen.  So I click the X to close it, and a dialog box appears stating that Explorer is not responding.  So I click to close it.  When I view the NAS device, I see New Folder, New Folder (1), New Folder (2), New Folder (3), etc.  I just keeps creating new folders until I can get Explorer to shutdown.  This last time it created 79 new folders.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Snap Server's configuration web page and go to:
   Network Settings -> Microsoft Networking and click on the button "Advanced"
   Unmark the following two items and let the Snap Server Restart
     - Enable Opportunistic Locking
     - Enable NT SMBs

That did the trick on my Windows 7/Snap Server combo.